# Android videoview random java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a videoView and loading video's from a remote server.
I'm getting random error as per below.
Problem is, it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Constants.API_IMAGE_HOST + "ads/video/" + this.adVideoObject.ad_videos_id + ".mp4"));
```

the error i get is:

```
MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource IOException happend :
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
```

Again, I get it sometimes but not always.

Comment: what is the value `Constants.API_IMAGE_HOST`. I guess you are accessing some `http` resources, you would need the Uri to be something like this `"http://example.com/ads/video/...."`

Comment: it is, it's the constant for the server name.

Comment: like i said, it works sometimes and sometimes doesnt. The url is for sure correct. I know the constand would assume it was an image, but it's not. It really gives the full url to the mp4 file. which, again, sometimes works and sometimes gives this error.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, as I have mentioned in numerous other posts about VideoView, DONT USE IT! I am a professional Android developer that develops apps that are all about video playback and in my experience, VideoView is entirely unreliable and is very difficult if not impossible to get it to behave correctly across multiple devices. I would strongly suggest for you to look into the ExoPlayer library if playback is at all important to your app. It is harder to setup but the performance and reliability improvements are soo worth it.

I apologize that this does not explicitly answer your question. However I believe that you will find the ExoPlayer library a pure joy to work with over VideoView or MediaPlayer.

Comment: thank you for this, looks like a winner, though... somehow i can't get it to display my surface... I've looked at the sample cod,e but it crashes on my phone and tablet. When implementing inside my app, i get no errors, but nothing is shown... i see a reference to a Surface, but I guess thats a surfaceview. Though I dont see anything ....

Comment: Without seeing some code I am unable to address your particular concern. However, I modified it to use a TextureView for my purposes it worked better. Maybe look into that?

Comment: How do i use a texture view for it?

Comment: I don't believe so FileNotFoundException happens for VideoView issue. It is an issue of content Uri, seldom content URI return's FileNotFoundException cause of File system modified and it works after reboot your OS. Though I dint got any workaround solution for this yet..

Answer (score 0):

The error

> D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : 
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://192.168.1.114:1376/%25/F885C5CE27F16C4D64588D48A3001A1B/9.mp4
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1137)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:988)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:911)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1102)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1093)

Is part of the normal flow of the VideoView setDataSource.  It tries to open the file locally, and then moves onto loading remotely.

Typically there will be a further error message which explains the actual failure.

In my case, it was `getDuration` being called in the incorrect state.  So look further down the logs, and check that you are following the state diagram in the documents and ensuring that the API is called only when the view is in the correct state